# Python: Transpose columns & duplicate rows

Tags: python, duplicates, transpose

I am a complete newbie with Python and I am trying to solve the following problem...

I have read in an excel file with pandas that looks something like this:

| Country | 2000 | 2001 | 2002 | 2003 | 2004 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Argentina | 1.23 | 4.56 | 7.89 | 10.11 | 12.13 | ... |
| Brazil | 14.15 | 16.17 | 18.19 | 20.21 | 22.23 | ... |
| Chile | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Colombia | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

And what I try to get is something like this:

| Country | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Argentina | 2000 | 1.23 |
| Argentina | 2001 | 4.56 |
| Argentina | 2002 | 7.89 |
| Argentina | 2003 | 10.11 |
| Argentina | 2004 | 12.13 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Brazil | 2000 | 14.15 |
| Brazil | 2001 | 16.17 |
| Brazil | 2002 | 18.19 |
| Brazil | 2003 | 20.21 |
| Brazil | 2004 | 22.23 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Chile | 2000 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |

I have already read a few posts about transposing, but have not found anything that addresses my problem.

Can someone help here?

Comment: Try `df.melt(ignore_index=False)`?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the answer. pd.melt() or df.melt() seem to go in the right direction. However, I get the following error with df.melt(ignore_index=False): melt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_index'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas.melt is useful for you to unpivot a dataframe.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

So, you can transform the dataframe to what you want as follows:

### Code

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'1.2.4'
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     "Country": ["Argentina", "Brazil",],
...     "2000": [1.23, 14.15,],
...     "2001": [4.56, 16.17,], 
...     "2002": [7.89, 18.19,],
...     "2003": [10.11, 20.21,],
...     "2004": [12.13, 22.23,],
... })  # Create sample data

>>> df
     Country   2000   2001   2002   2003   2004
0  Argentina   1.23   4.56   7.89  10.11  12.13
1     Brazil  14.15  16.17  18.19  20.21  22.23

>>> df.melt(id_vars="Country", var_name="Year", value_name="Value")
     Country  Year  Value
0  Argentina  2000   1.23
1     Brazil  2000  14.15
2  Argentina  2001   4.56
3     Brazil  2001  16.17
4  Argentina  2002   7.89
5     Brazil  2002  18.19
6  Argentina  2003  10.11
7     Brazil  2003  20.21
8  Argentina  2004  12.13
9     Brazil  2004  22.23

>>> # If you want to sort the records by "Country":
>>> df.melt(id_vars="Country", var_name="Year", value_name="Value").sort_values("Country").reset_index(drop=True)
     Country  Year  Value
0  Argentina  2000   1.23
1  Argentina  2001   4.56
2  Argentina  2002   7.89
3  Argentina  2003  10.11
4  Argentina  2004  12.13
5     Brazil  2000  14.15
6     Brazil  2001  16.17
7     Brazil  2002  18.19
8     Brazil  2003  20.21
9     Brazil  2004  22.23
```

Thanks :)